# Java FX buttons slightly smaller when clicked/focus

Tags: java, css, button, javafx, fxml

I have an issue where my buttons in JavaFX become slightly smaller when clicked.

[here](https://gyazo.com/8b1a78f70c553084522547c8a5e038e9) you can see that the "change password" button is clicked/selected.

[here](https://gyazo.com/e5f328e57bf0c6c454800f05eb21e4e1) you can see the "admin functions" button is clicked/selected.

I suspected this was something to do with the buttons having focus, as when i click chrome or another application with this running, it reverts to desired [look](https://gyazo.com/1af40ec01e6755872fdb1923ee46e502)

the buttons are currently within a 4x1 GridPane, with the 0th slot being occupied by the label.

here is my CSS if it helps:

```
.button{
-fx-border-color: null;
-fx-border-width: 0;
-fx-background-color: #2c3cff;
-fx-fill: true;
-fx-pref-height: 100;
-fx-pref-width: 320;
-fx-text-fill: #b9b9b9;
-fx-border-radius: 0;
-fx-min-width: 320;
-fx-min-height: 100;
-fx-background-radius: 0;
-fx-animated: false;

}


.grid{
    -fx-background-color:#3e3e48;
}

.label{
    -fx-text-fill: #b9b9b9;
}
```

> Edit: I have found a temporary "solution", more of a workaround: I put
>   a horizontal separator just below my HBox and this allowed me to mask
>   the weird button size changes. would still like answers about how to
>   do this properly.
>
> Thanks!

Comment: `-fx-animated`? Is this a `Button` or a `JFXButton` you're asking about?

Comment: @fabian it is a button from the `javafx.scene.control.Button` import, also i tried `-fx-animated: false;` but no luck there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I figured it out after a long time of trying to use workarounds such as the separator.

The default FX stylesheet applied this to all buttons:

```
    -fx-background-insets: 0 0 -1 0, 0, 1, 2;
```

and whilst in my `.button:focused` definition i had set these to 0, in my `.button` definition i had not, so it had taken the insets value from the default CSS. by applying `-fx-background-insets: 0,0,0,0,0;` to both `.button` and `.button:hover` i was able to achieve the desired result.

> Note: you can just type `-fx-background-insets: 0;` i left the full values in in case i want to change at a later date.